# Deploy Gatsby to Firebase using Circleci

Tags: firebase, gatsby, firebase-hosting, circleci, firebase-tools

I followed this blog to deploy my Gatsby site to Firebase using circleCI

https://circleci.com/blog/automatically-deploy-a-gatsby-site-to-firebase-hosting/

The config.yml file is as follows

```
# CircleCI Firebase Deployment Config
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10
    working_directory: ~/gatsby-site
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            # Find a cache corresponding to this specific package-lock.json
            - v1-npm-deps-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
            # Fallback cache to be used
            - v1-npm-deps-
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: npm install
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-npm-deps-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
          paths:
            - ./node_modules
      - run:
          name: Gatsby Build
          command: npm run build
      - run:
          name: Firebase Deploy
          command: ./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN"
```

This caused an error

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN"
/bin/bash: ./node_modules/.bin/firebase: No such file or directory

Exited with code exit status 127
CircleCI received exit code 127
```

I haven't used yml files or focused on devops before so did some digging around. Found a few other people with this issue and there was a suggestion to use workspaces and workflow. So I amended my yml file to support this

```
# CircleCI Firebase Deployment Config
version: 2
jobs:
  #build jobs
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10
    working_directory: ~/gatsby-site
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            # Find a cache corresponding to this specific package-lock.json
            - v1-npm-deps-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
            # Fallback cache to be used
            - v1-npm-deps-
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: npm install
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-npm-deps-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
          paths:
            - ./node_modules
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ./
          paths:
            - ./
      - run:
          name: Gatsby Build
          command: npm run build
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ./
          paths:
            - ./
  # deploy jobs
  deploy-production:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ./  
      - run:
          name: Firebase Deploy
          command: ./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN"
workflows:
  version: 2
  build:
    jobs:
    #build
      - build
    #deploy
      - deploy-production:
          requires:
            - build
```

Same issue

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN"
/bin/bash: ./node_modules/.bin/firebase: No such file or directory

Exited with code exit status 127
CircleCI received exit code 127
```

I assume it must be something to do with the paths and it's looking in the wrong directory? Any idea of how I can get it to find the module required?

Comment: Is `firebase-tools` listed in your `package.json`?

Comment: You've made my day! npm install -D firebase-tools did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I can't read. The fix was in the instructions

> We’ll also need to install the firebase-tools package locally to our
>   project as a devDependency. This will come in handy later on when
>   integrating with CircleCI, which does not allow installing packages
>   globally by default. So let’s install it right now:
>
> npm install -D firebase-tools